# Does Helmholtz Decomposition make sense for $\hat{r}/r^2$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, divergence-operator, curl

Consider an inverse square vector field $\vec{F}$ and it's curl and divergence shown below

$$\vec{F} = \hat{r}/r^2\\
\nabla \times \vec{F} = \vec{0}\\
\nabla \cdot \vec{F} = 0
$$

$\vec{F}$ is defined over all space *except* the origin. This is important because it says that the domain of $\vec{F}$ is *not* simply connected. Let's apply [Helmholtz decomposition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition#Statement_of_the_theorem)
over a simply connected domain $V \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ (I just want to avoid the trouble point at the origin. In order to apply Helmholtz, I don't know if the domain has to be simply connected, but let's just assume $V$ is simply connected anyways - Wikipedia says that $V$ just needs to be a domain over which $\vec{F}$ is a class $C^2$ function). Anyways, I decompose $\vec{F}$ into

$$\vec{F} = \nabla{\Phi} + \nabla \times \vec{A} $$

The potential $\Phi$ and the vector potential $\vec{A}$ are made out of two terms each. In the context of $\vec{F} = \hat{r}/r^2$, we are left with

$$ 
\Phi = \oint_{\text{surface of V}} \cdots \ dS \\
\vec{A} = \oint_{\text{surface of V}} \cdots \ dS
$$

**Question**
Does Helmholtz theorem make sense or did I apply it incorrectly? I already know that $\Phi$ should be $-1/r$ since

$$ \nabla \Big(-\frac{1}{r}\Big) = \frac{\hat{r}}{r^2}$$

The only way I can make sense of Helmholtz theorem is if $\vec{A}$ happens to be $\vec{0}$ so that the curl of $\vec{0}$ is zero. Or maybe $\vec{A}$ is a constant, so that the curl of a constant is zero. Or just in general $\vec{A}$ has to be conservative (say $\nabla \lambda$) so that $\nabla \times \nabla\lambda = \vec{0}$. Or maybe $\vec{A} = \text{co}\vec{\text{ns}}\text{t} + \nabla\lambda$ so that the curl is $0$. Is this correct?

**Question**
If you have a vector field that is completely specified by a vector potential $\vec{F} = \nabla \times \vec{A}$, then it follows that the divergence of $\vec{F}$ is $0$. I know the logic doesn't follow the other way around. But I *thought* that if you know a vector field is divergence free *and* the domain is simply connected, then $\vec{F}$ is completely specified by a vector potential. Is this not true? I know that the inverse square field has a divergence of $0$. Over simply connected domains not containing the origin, does it not follow that $\hat{r}/r^2$ is completely specified by some vector potential $\vec{A}$, in which case $\Phi$ has to be a constant so that $\nabla \Phi = 0$? In my first question, I found $\Phi$ and concluded the form of $\vec{A}$ to make the curl $0$. Now I'm asking, couldn't $\vec{F}$ over simply connected domains be specified via the curl of $\vec{A}$, in which case I would have to conclude that $\Phi$ is a constant so the gradient is $0$?

Comment: First of all, when you take a point out of $\Bbb R^3$, the resulting space *is* simply connected (so any curl-free vector field *does* have a potential function). However, the *second* (co)homology does not vanish, and this tells you that a divergence-free vector field may indeed fail to be the curl of some field. That's what's going on here.

Comment: Hmm interesting. I was thinking of simply connected as being any domain in which you an shrink any closed curve down into a point. In $\mathbb{R}^2$ removing a point would make it not simply connected. But in $R^3$, remove a point and consider a "unit circle closed curve" around that point. I can shrink this curve into a point, but doesn't it hit the removed point? I guess in $\mathbb{R}^3$, you can warp this curve while you shrink it down in order to avoid the hole? If I may ask a few more follow up questions, over a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ in which $\nabla \cdot \hat{r}/r^2 = 0$ for all

Comment: @TedShifrin of the subset, shouldn't $\hat{r}/r^2$ be expressible as the curl of some field?

Comment: But that equation holds on all of $\Bbb R^3-\{0\}$, and, on *that entire domain* the vector field is *not* a curl. To see that, it suffices to notice that the flux across the unit sphere is nonzero. By Stokes's Theorem, the flux of a curl across a closed surface is always $0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Is it correct to say if the divergence is 0 over all of $\mathbb{R}^3$, then the vector field is a curl? Second, can you apply Helmholtz's theorem to $\hat{r}/r^2$ over $\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash {0}$? In my question, I was applying Helmholtz's theorem to a ball of space in $\mathbb{R}^3$ not containing the origin. But in this ball of space, just over this domain, can $\hat{r}/r^2$ be expressed as a curl? My assumption was yes. Then my question was trying to show how this assumption contradicts Helmholtz's theorem applied to the ball. But I know I have confusion somewhere

Comment: Yes, as long as the second cohomology vanishes (which is true for any star-shaped region, for example), a divergence-free field will be a curl.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inverse-Square vector fields have both a divergence and curl of $0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2786581/inverse-square-vector-fields-have-both-a-divergence-and-curl-of-0)

Comment: @MarkViola I'm the one that asked that question

Comment: Yes, and you're asking effectively the same question.  I suggest that if you would like a wider participation, then offer a bounty.  Otherwise, it is considered bad form to post a question that one has asked before.